# How to save picklist value in custom lightning datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, picklist, html, lightning-datatable

I have just started working with Lightning Web Components, and I am attempting to add picklist functionality to my datatable. My standard cell edits/saves are working as intended, but I am unable to save newly selected picklist values. The original source I'm referencing for picklists in a datatable can be found here: ([Picklist in Lightning Datatable](https://live.playg.app/play/picklist-in-lightning-datatable)).

I've loaded my .js with console.log statements. Here are my revisions:

customDatatableDemo.js

```javascript
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getPayments from '@salesforce/apex/PaymentController.getPayments';
import saveRecords from '@salesforce/apex/PaymentController.saveRecords';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

import 

export default class CustomDatatableDemo extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    //have this attribute to track data changed
    //with custom picklist or custom lookup  
    @track draftValues = [];

    @track lastSavedData = [];

    connectedCallback() { 
        this.columns = [
            {
            label: 'Name',
            fieldName: 'Name',
            editable: false
        }, {
            label: 'Invoice Number',
            fieldName: 'Invoice_Number__c',
            editable: true
        }, {
            label: 'Invoice Amount',
            fieldName: 'Invoice_Amount__c',
            type: 'currency',
            editable: true
        }, {
            label: 'Invoice Date',
            fieldName: 'Invoice_Date__c',
            type: 'date',
            editable: true
        }, {
            label: 'Payment Status',
            fieldName: 'Payment_Status__c',
            type: 'picklist',
            typeAttributes:
            {
                placeholder: 'Choose Status',
                options: [
                    { label: 'Needs to Be Paid', value: 'Needs to Be Paid' },
                    { label: 'Issued', value: 'Issued' },
                    { label: 'Voided', value: 'Voided' },
                ] // List of Payment Status picklist options
                , value: {fieldName: 'Payment_Status__c' } // default value for picklist
                , context: {fieldName: 'Id' } // binding Payment Id with context variable to be returned back
            }
            },
            {
                label: 'Description', fieldName: 'Work_Description__c', type: 'text', editable: true
            }];
    
        //  Get Payments data
        getPayments()
        .then(result => {
            this.data = result;
            this.error = undefined;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        })

        // Save last saved copy
        this.lastSavedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
    }   

    updateDataValues(updateItem) {
        console.log('START--updateDataValues()');
        console.log('updateItem = ' + JSON.stringify(updateItem));
        let copyData = [... this.draftValues];
        copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.draftValues));

        console.log('copyData = ' + JSON.stringify(copyData));
        copyData.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                console.log('item.Id === updateItem.Id ? item.Id = ' + JSON.stringify(item.Id) + ' updateItem.Id = ' + JSON.stringify(updateItem.Id));
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    console.log('updateDataValues() item.Id = ' + JSON.stringify(updateItem.Id));
                    console.log('updateItem[field] = ' + JSON.stringify(updateItem[field]));
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                    console.log('UPDATED--item[field] = ' + updateItem[field]);
                }
            }
        });

        this.data = [...copyData];

        console.log('this.data = [...copyData] = ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
        /*
        console.log('copyData = ' + JSON.stringify(copyData));

        //write changes back to original data
        this.data = [...copyData];
        console.log('this.data = ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
        let tempData = [...this.data];
        //console.log('tempData = ' + JSON.stringify(tempData));
        console.log('END--updateDataValues()');
        */
    }

    updateDraftValues(updateItem) {
        console.log('START--updateDraftValues()');
        console.log('updateItem.value = ' + JSON.stringify(updateItem.value));
        console.log('stringify draft updateItem = ' + JSON.stringify(updateItem));
        let draftValueChanged = false;
        let copyDraftValues = [...this.data];
        copyDraftValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
        //store changed value to do operations
        //on save. This will enable inline editing &
        //show standard cancel & save button
        let i = 0;

        let newUpdatedItem = {...updateItem};
        newUpdatedItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(updateItem));

        console.log('****newUpdatedItem = ' + JSON.stringify(newUpdatedItem));

        copyDraftValues.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === newUpdatedItem.Id) {
        
                
                i++;
                console.log('i = ' + i);
                for (let field in newUpdatedItem) {
                    console.log('item Id = ' + item.Id + ' & item value = ' + item.Payment_Status__c);
                    item[field] = newUpdatedItem[field];
                    console.log('item[field] = ' + newUpdatedItem[field]);
                }
                
                draftValueChanged = true;
                console.log('draftValueChanged = TRUE');
            }
        });

        //draftValueChanged = true;

        if (draftValueChanged) {
            console.log('YESdraftValueChanged');
            console.log('copyDraftValues = ' + JSON.stringify(copyDraftValues));
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues];
            //console.log('draftValues = ' + JSON.stringify(draftValues));
        } else {
            console.log('NOdraftValue!Changed');
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues, updateItem];
            let testDraftValues = {... this.draftValues};
            console.log('JSON.stringify(testDraftValues) = ' + JSON.stringify(testDraftValues));
        }
        console.log('STOP--updateDraftValues()')
    }

    //listener handler to get the context and data
    //updates datatable
    picklistChanged(event) {
        console.log('START--picklistChanged()');
        console.log('EVENT type - ' + event.type);
        event.stopPropagation();
        let dataReceived = event.detail.data;

        let updatedItem = {...dataReceived};
        updatedItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(updatedItem));

        console.log('!!!! updatedItem = ' + JSON.stringify(updatedItem));

        updatedItem = { Id: updatedItem.context , Payment_Status__c: updatedItem.value };
        console.log('picklistChanged()...updatedItem = ' + JSON.stringify(updatedItem));
        this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
        this.updateDataValues(updatedItem);
        console.log('STOP--picklistChanged()');
    }

    /*
    handleSelection(event) {
        console.log('START--handleSelection()');
        this.updateDraftValues(event.detail.draftValues[0]);
        console.log('this.updateDraftValues(event.detail.draftValues[0]);')
        event.stopPropogation();
        let dataReceived = event.detail.data;
        let updatedItem = { ...dataReceived };
        this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
        this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
        console.log('STOP--handleSelection() = ' + JSON.stringify(updatedItem));
    }
    */

    //handler to handle cell changes & update values in draft values
    handleCellChange(event) {
        console.log('START--handleCellChange()');
        console.log('handleCellChange');
        this.updateDraftValues(event.detail.draftValues[0]);
        console.log('handleCellChange value = ' + JSON.stringify(this.updateDraftValues));
        console.log('END--handleCellChange()');
    }

    handleSave(event) {
        if (event.type === 'picklistchanged'){

        }
        console.log('START--handleSave');
        console.log('Updated items = ', this.draftValues);
        // save last saved copy
        this.lastSavedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
        console.log('this.lastSavedData = ' + JSON.stringify(this.lastSavedData));

        this.fldsItemValues = event.detail.draftValues;
        console.log('this.fldsItemValues = ' + JSON.stringify(this.fldsItemValues));

        const inputsItems = this.fldsItemValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            console.log('JSON.stringify() fields ' + JSON.stringify(fields));
            return { fields };
        });

       // Show toast after successful update
        const promises = inputsItems.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        console.log('BEGIN const promises... ');
        Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Records Updated Successfully!!',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            this.fldsItemValues = [];
            return this.refresh();
        }).catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'An Error Occured!!',
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }).finally(() => {
            // Clear draft values
            this.draftValues = [];
        });

        
        // Refresh the window after successful save
        //window.open('url','_self');
        //document.location.reload(true);
        
        //cmp.find("table-component-id").set("v.draftValues", null);
        console.log('END--handleSave');
    }

    handleCancel(event) {
        //remove draftValues & revert data changes
        this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lastSavedData));
        this.draftValues = [];
    }

    async refresh() {
        console.log('async refresh');
        await refreshApex(this.data);
        //this.connectedCallback();
    }
}
```

Here are my console logs after selecting and saving a picklist value:
[image: Console (1)]

[image: Console (2)]

I am still trying to figure out what I am doing wrong when attempting to save the picklist value. I'm still learning lightning development, and I would appreciate any advice from the community. Thank you!

Comment: did you get the solution?
i also need this can you please share with html